# Excel Macro to add a week to the beginning date in column B repetitively until a new value is found in column A. Non-VBA could also work

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I have an excel sheet with a value of 980002 for x amount of lines. After x amount of lines a new number will appear in column A. In column B I need to insert a date that is the same date for 3 lines and then add a week for the next 3 lines until the first value of 980002 ends. Then repeat the same process for the next value in column A.

(Edit): This is my new set of code I have but I cant get it to only write the date in the cell next to 980002 until that value ends. Instead it counts the rows of 980002 and writes that many dates adding 3 rows inbetween each cell.
For example if there is 5 rows with a value of 980002 then it will write 5 dates but from row 1 to row 15.

```
 Sub years()  
Dim cmdate As Date  
Dim i As Integer  
Dim rng As Range  
Dim cll As Range  
i = 0  
cmdate = DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, 1)  
Set rng = Range("a1", Range("a1").End(xlDown))  
For Each cll In rng  
If cll.Value = "980002" Then  
Do  
Range("B1").Offset(i, 0) = cmdate  
cmdate = cmdate + 7  
i = i + 3  
Loop Until Range("a1") <= "980002"  
End If  
Next cll  
End Sub
```

[The expected output would be something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNU9t.png)

Comment: I need the code to put a date of 1/1/2019 in the first 3 cells then add 7 days to be put in the next 3 cells and repeat this process until the value of 980002 ends then repeat the same process for the next value of 980004 starting with the same date of 1/1/2019.

Comment: Hey @jkoburi ,, instead of VBA macro I could suggest you method using Excel formula will generate dates like,, `01/01/19 in 3 Rows` then `01/08/19 in next 3 Rows` and repeat `01/01/19 in 3 Rows` then `01/08/19 in next 3 Rows`,, please confirm through comments if it works for you, also [Edit] your post and add that **NOO VBA** method will  also works.

Comment: @Rajesh S I need a macro to do this as I will have a document with thousands of lines that will need dates added to them.

Comment: Okay @jkoburi no issue,, hope soon someone post the required VBA code !

Comment: Is your data in column A already sorted? If yes, then you would only need one `For Each cll In rng`. In the loop, store the value of the current cell to compare with the next iteration. Add in the extra criteria if you put in date 3 times to increment it. If not sorted, then you'll probably need some filter command to loop through your data. I hope this is enough for you to fill in the blanks...

Comment: @gns100 The data is sorted. Can you show me some code on how to do this as I am not fully aware on how to implement your idea into the code. Thanks in advance!

Comment: We are not a script writing service. Perhaps it's best for you to go beyond thinking of the problem and attempt to write pseudo code to get the logic down. From there, translation to VBA shouldn't be that difficult (although it may still be time consuming).

Comment: @gns100 Sorry I don't know VBA at all and just put this code together from the little knowledge ive learned. I appreciate the ideas but don't know how to write the ideas into the code.

Comment: In my opinion, it seems like you already have the VBA that you need, setting ranges/variable, `for...each` loop, the `if`condition, writing to a value to a cell. I'm saying you need to think about the logic and string these pieces together. Maybe instead of trying to write the whole program in one shot, start with milestones.  put dates in column B, increment the date by change on column A value, increment the date by every third row, etc. We can help debug your iterations.

Comment: @gns100 I have updated the code and still cant seem to get it to work. If you have any new suggestions it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @jkoburi,,  now you have twisted the question,, earlier it was,, similar date in 3 rows,, then +7 until the new code found and repeat the previous procedure ,, for example `01/01/19` in 1st 3 rows then `01/08/19` in next rows and for new code again `01/01/19` & so on for the rest. If this is the issue then I've already fixed the issue using non vba method,, confirm through comments. Or better [Edit] the post and add expected output alongside, will help us to go further !!

Comment: @RajeshS Yes that is the issue. To better clarify it would be 1st 3 rows 1/1/19 then 1/8/19 next 3 rows until the value in column a changes to the next value of 980004 and start back over at 1/1/19 for the 1st 3 rows and so on.

Comment: @RajeshS Id be willing to see how it would work but this is just a small scale example so that's why I was more leaning towards a macro to do the coding for me. If it does the job then I am open to it. I appreciate your help so far!

Comment: @jkoburi,, oh not again ,,, you are simply giving many twist to the issue.. BUT yes this can be solved and I would suggest Excel Formula (a non VBA method),, if this works confirm through comments also [Edit] your post and add that you accept a NON VBA method also !!

Comment: @RajeshS I think I edited the post like you were asking.

Comment: @jkoburi,, ok on next few minutes  I'll post the solution ☺

Answer (score 0):

*To get the series of dates in desire order, I would like to suggest a Non VBA method.*

[image]

**How it works:**

- Put initial date in cell `AB1` (is editable also).
- Enter this formula in cell `AB2` & fill it down.

  `=COUNTIF($AA$2:$AA2,$AA2)`
- Formula in cell `AC2`.

  ```
  =IF(ISBLANK(AB2),"",IF(AND(AB2>=1,AB2<=3),$AB$1,IF(AND(AB2>=4,AB2<=6),$AB$1+7,IF(AND(AB2>=7,AB2<=9),$AB$1+14))))
  ```

---

*For neatness later on you may hide the `AB` Column.*

[image]

---

**Edit:** *I'm including this part since the OP is confused that how the shown method will works if set of IDs vary.*

- This example comprises series of 6 similar IDs.

[image]

- Forula in cell `T2`:

`=COUNTIF($S$2:$S2,$S2)`

- Formula in cell `U2`:

  ```
  =IF(AND(T2>=1,T2<=3),$T$1,IF(AND(T2>=4,T2<=6),$T$1+7))
  ```

**Adjust date calculation and cell references in the formula as needed.**

Comment: This would work great but on a small scale. After 9 lines of a specific value that formula fails. How would I get this formula to work for say 500 lines of that same value? Without having to write the if statements for every 3 lines?

Comment: @jkoburi,, what do you mean by Formula fails after 9 lines,, what ID pattern you have used,, (attached Screen Shot), this  works for second 9 lines also and will work for others also ,,, I can't use 500 or 1000 lines for example ,, the suggested method works for every 9 lines!!

Comment: @jkoburi,, for set of 3 or 6 lines the COUNTIF generates list and it works,,, I think you are unable to adjust cell references with the formula. For your understanding I'm editing the post and adding example with set of 6 !!

Comment: I understand the formula you have provided but what im saying is if I have 100 lines of that same value in column a (980002) I would need to write more if statements for every 3 lines. The second example you provided is moving in the opposite direction that I would need to go. Your first example only worked for the first 9 lines of a value then if I were to put in 9 more lines on that same value it would say false instead of continuing the dates.

Comment: @jkoburi,, I think you are little confused ,, and let me say **how could you skip from formula writing** and it's one time job,, then copy down !!